# How to calculate how much market value depends on a certain variable

Tags: calculus, functions

Me and my colleague disagree regarding about how much the market value for real estate depends on a certain variable.
For simplicity let us assume that the market value for a property is calculated as the following:

$MV = \frac{NOI}{y}$

where MV = Market value, NOI = Net operating income, y=exit-yield

Let's say that we want to compare the property value in year one (MV<sub>1</sub>) to the property value in year 2 (MV<sub>2</sub>).

So we have:

$MV_{1} = \frac{NOI_{1}}{y_{1}}$ and $MV_{2} = \frac{NOI_{2}}{y_{2}}$

So the change in market value between year 1 and year 2 is: $MV_{2}$ - $MV_{1}$

Now to the main question: How do I explain how much the Net operating income (NOI) has affected the change in MV? Then the same question for the exit-yield (y)?

One of us argues like the following:

The exit-yield affect is $\frac{NOI_{1}}{y_{2}} - MV_{1}$
and the NOI affect is $\frac{NOI_{2}}{y_{1}} - MV_{1}$

The other person argues like the following:

The exit-yield affect is  $MV_{2} - \frac{NOI_{2}}{y_{1}}$
and the NOI affect is $MV_{2} - \frac{NOI_{1}}{y_{2}}$

They don't add up to the total value change, but that we agree about. The difference we call "Other" effects on the market value (maybe there is a way to have the NOI and y explain the whole difference?)